# How to list Access Control List?

Tags: list, permissions, cmd, acl

Is there a command that can list all the Permissions of a file/folder?

I need to be able to list permission from Novell Server as well as Windows Server for integrity checking.

I have searched through and found "icacls" but I believe it can only change permission.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

For the windows side (it's been almost 20 years since I played with Novell)

icacls can definitely dump permissions, just run icacls /? for the usage information.

If you find that is difficult to read, you might prefer to use dumpsec instead http://www.systemtools.com/somarsoft/index.html